# select distinct rows order by date

Tags: sql

I have a table (below) that i'd like to select on. I want to group by printorder and also order by lastsaved descending

```
Id  docid   printorder  lastsaved
1   1       1           2012-03-30 15:20:14.990
5   1       2           2012-03-30 15:20:15.733
9   1       1           2012-03-30 15:33:33.330
```

I thought this would be a simple query but i'm struggling! If anyone can help that would be great

*Edit* Here is the query i've been working with

```
SELECT DISTINCT(printorder), id, lastsaved, docid
FROM bpdocsides a
WHERE a.docid = 1
ORDER BY lastsaved DESC
```

Answer (score 4):

So you are clear, you won't be able to select from that table and group by printorder unless you also group by all the other columns or you use some sort of aggregate function on the remaining columns (MAX,SUM, etc.). Further, if you intend to select Id, you might as well select everything from the table since there won't be any repeated records for column id.

In other words:

```
select id, docid, printorder , lastsaved from table
group by printorder,docid,id,lastsaved 
order by lastsaved
```

will be equivalent to do

```
select id, docid, printorder , lastsaved 
from bpdocsides 
order by lastsaved
```

Maybe you really want something like:

```
select docid, printorder , max(lastsaved)
from bpdocsides 
group by printorder,docid
order by max(lastsaved)
```

**EDIT**

You need this:

```
 select docid, printorder , max(lastsaved)
 from bpdocsides 
 group by printorder,docid
 where docid=1
 order by max(lastsaved)
```

Comment: The problem with your query is ordering by the lastsaved field. Column "bpdocsides.lastsaved" is invalid in the ORDER BY clause because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like the following:

```
SELECT DISTINCT printorder, id, lastsaved, docid
FROM bpdocsides a
WHERE a.docid = 1
ORDER BY lastsaved DESC
```

Comment: That will not be distinct to the printorder column

Comment: Unfortunately this does not distinct on the printorder field

Comment: yes it will not be distinct bcoz there are many columns with repeated values i just trying to post that it should not be distinct() as i  commented

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix this myself.

```
select distinct docid, 
(select max(lastsaved) from bpdocsides a where a.docid = b.docid) from bpdocsides b
```

Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 0):

Your code will work on Postgre sql and some similar to postgre. Try this query:

```
select 
     distinct on (printorder) Id, docid, printorder, lastsaved         
from 
     bpdocsides a 
where 
     a.docid = 1 
order by 
     lastsaved desc
```

I added the `ON` clause and removed the extra comma. Again this will only work on PostgreSQL. The other databases do do support this syntax.

You can try this query and see if it works for you. It should work if you have a major database system:

```
select b1.* from
(
    select             
        printorder, 
        max(lastsaved) as lastsaved
    from       
        bpdocsides
    group by printorder
) a1
join
(
    select 
        Id, 
        docid, 
        printorder, 
        lastsaved
    from 
        bpdocsides
    where       
        docid = 1 
) b1 on a1.printorder=b1.printorder and a1.lastsaved=b1.lastsaved
```

Comment: I get:
`ERROR: SELECT DISTINCT ON expressions must match initial ORDER BY expressions`